# How to write this complex SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have three identical tables in my MySQL table namely

**first_term_result, second_term_result and third_term_result**

this are the columns in it

```
exam_type_id | student_id  | subject_id  | mark  |
```

or example with dummy data

**NOTE:** there are three different exam type for each subjects (CA1, CA2, CA3 and Exam),
          there are three table like this with same thing but different data as it hold data for first term another for second term and the last for third term.

```
first_term_result:

exam_type_id | student_id  | subject_id  | mark  |
    1        |    6        |     7       | 12    |
    2        |    6        |     7       | 9     |
    3        |    6        |     7       | 13    |   
    4        |    6        |     7       | 45    |
    1        |    4        |     7       | 7     |
    2        |    4        |     7       | 5     |
    3        |    4        |     7       | 10    |   
    4        |    4        |     7       | 34    |

second_term_result:

exam_type_id | student_id  | subject_id  | mark  |
    1        |    6        |     7       | 15    |
    2        |    6        |     7       | 6     |
    3        |    6        |     7       | 10    |   
    4        |    6        |     7       | 50    |
    1        |    4        |     7       | 6     |
    2        |    4        |     7       | 3     |
    3        |    4        |     7       | 9     |   
    4        |    4        |     7       | 44    |


third_term_result:

exam_type_id | student_id  | subject_id  | mark  |
    1        |    6        |     7       | 17    |
    2        |    6        |     7       | 8     |
    3        |    6        |     7       | 15    |   
    4        |    6        |     7       | 67    |
    1        |    4        |     7       | 12    |
    2        |    4        |     7       | 8     |
    3        |    4        |     7       | 12    |   
    4        |    4        |     7       | 50    |
```

Now what i want to achieve is get the `SUM()` of `first_term_result.mark` `second_term_result.mark` and `third_term_result.mark` of each students `WHERE` subject_id=7 group by students name.

another very important problem is i will be calculating the grand sum for each students for first_term+second_term+third_term and also want to be able to order the grand total for that student and the subjects in DESC so i can position them accordingly please if it will be easier on php please let me know.

Thanks

it seems very complex to me but i know there are gurus here who ca achieve this, i read somewhere that it is possible to order by even when rollup is used.

below is my code which doesn't work obviously.

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.fname,' ',s.mname,' ',s.lname) AS sname, 
SUM(f.mark) AS first_total, 
SUM(se.mark) AS second_total, 
SUM(t.mark) AS third_total 
SUM(f.first_total,second.total,third_total) as GT // just to show my intention 
FROM students s, first_term_result f, second_term_result se, third_term_result t 
WHERE s.studentID=f.student_id AND
s.studentID=se.student_id AND
s.studentID=t.student_id AND
f.subject_id=7 AND
se.subject_id=7 AND
t.subject_id=7
GROUP BY sname ORDER BY GT DESC
```

Comment: It will be far less complex if you further normalize your data. Make a column for term and keep all terms in the same table.

Comment: @DMac seriously this has made me dumb, can seem to know how i can achieve same if i keep all terms on same table

Comment: *complex* :D We use queries with up to 200 lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(MS.fname,' ',MS.mname,' ',MS.lname) AS sname, 
  M.FTotal, M.STotal, M.TTotal, 
  (M.FTotal + M.STotal + M.TTotal) AS GrandTotal
FROM (
  SELECT st.studentID, 
     (
       SELECT SUM(f.mark) 
       FROM first_term_result AS f 
       WHERE f.subject_id = 7 
       AND f.student_id = st.studentID
     ) AS FTotal, 
     (
       SELECT SUM(s.mark) 
       FROM second_term_result AS s 
       WHERE s.subject_id = 7 
       AND s.student_id = st.studentID
     ) AS STotal, 
     (
       SELECT SUM(t.mark) 
       FROM third_term_result AS t 
       WHERE t.subject_id = 7 
       AND t.student_id = st.studentID
     ) AS TTotal
  FROM students AS st
  WHERE st.studentID IN (
    SELECT studentID 
    FROM first_term_result AS fs 
    WHERE fs.subject_id = 7 
    AND fs.student_id = st.studentID)
  GROUP BY st.studentID
) AS M
JOIN students MS ON M.studentID = MS.studentID
ORDER BY (M.FTotal + M.STotal + M.TTotal) DESC
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I created sub queries to pull the totals for each term.

Comment: OMG! this works but listed all students names from students table which doesnt have mark on results table i think LEFT JOIN on the results table could fix it, will appreciate sir

Comment: I added a `WHERE` clause to the inner query.  It only adds the student if there is a `first_term_result` record for them.

Comment: thanks! solved that seems a complex query to me, i should still learn more of such